# How do I filter the wordpress function get_comment_reply_link?

Tags: wordpress, tags, comments, reply

I am trying to filter the html being returned by the wordpress function ***get_comment_reply_link()*** using following code.

```
function remove_ntshow($content){
    echo "Dummy Text " . $content;
    return "";

}
add_filter('get_comment_reply_link', 'remove_ntshow', 145);
```

It should output **Dummy Text and whatever the content is**.
Finally, I need to output something like this...

```
<a class="btn-cust btn-commentReply" href="http://stackoverflow.com/posts/"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-reply"></i></a>
```

However, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `comment_reply_link()` it displays a link that lets users post a comment in reply to a specific comment.

```
function remove_ntshow($content){
         echo "<a class='btn-cust btn-commentReply' href='http://stackoverflow.com/posts/'><i class='fa fa-fw fa-reply'></i></a>" . $content;
        return "";        
}
add_filter('comment_reply_link', 'remove_ntshow', 145);
```